# Unexpected Case Sensitive Issue Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am working on a Laravel project and started receiving some unexpected issues.

I am running a script through a cron job, and there is an `if` condition in the script:

```
if($bride->photographer == 'yes'){
    // Code goes here
}
```

The problem is that up until yesterday everything was working fine but today it stopped working. When I started debugging I came to know that **it is not working for the values = "Yes"**. If the value starts with a capital Y it doesn't meet the condition. In short, it has started behaving as **Case Sensitive**.

I am wondering what has changed since yesterday. **If it is not working now then why was it working before?**

Comment: Where is this `'yes'` coming from? because indeed, the case sensitivity isn't just going to change

Comment: Always convert your string to lowercase when comparing with some string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always follow the simple rule when comparing user input value to some string:

```
if (strtolower( trim( $bride->photographer ) ) == 'yes') {
    // Code goes here
}
```

- Trim it.
- Convert it to `lowercase` or `uppercase`
- Compare it.

Comment: It is fine, but it's not the Answer of my question, i want to know why it was working before?

Comment: Check what **$bride->photographer** contains in it

Comment: it contains Yes, and i know the condition i applied should return false all the time, but i am just wondering why it was working before, it has stopped working now, which is ok, because it fails because of case sensitive issue, but how it was working before

Comment: OK, is this value coming from textbox or dropdown or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135668/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-insomania).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do when working with user input strings is to cast them either to uppercase or lowercase before comparing. So in your case, it would be best to do something like this:

```
if (strtolower($bride->photographer) === 'yes') {
    // Code goes here
}
```

[`strtolower`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) will make sure the value of `$bride->photographer` is always in lowercase.